# how to add confirm functionality in a button event handler using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a button that resets the hit counter in a page to zero. Now I want to add a confirmation dialogue box that appears when the button is pressed and gives the user a choice to either cancel or execute the reset.

Here is my code:

```
 <input type="button" value="Expire Cookie" onclick="document.cookie = 'visits=0';document.write(0);" />
```

any ideas? Please help me out here.. :(

Comment: Google for “confirmation dialogue”. But it’s [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/), not [“javascript”](http://PointedEars.de/es-matrix/).

Comment: Googled for "javascript confirm button", it returned this link: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_confirm.asp

Comment: I did but Im confused with the illustrations I saw @PointedEars :(

Comment: [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok this is what I did and it works :)

```
 function cdelete()
 {
var x = confirm("Please confirm you want to expire cookie?");
if (x == true) {
    document.cookie = 'visits=0';
    document.write(0);
}

 }
```

Thanks you everyone :)

Comment: It's _DOM_, so you should write `window.confirm`.  Also `if (x == true)` is the same as `if (x)`. `==` is a type-converting comparison, `===` is strict (but unnecessary here). `document.write(0)` is a mistake, it would overwrite the document in memory (as rendered). What did you intend?

Comment: I do have a cookie this is just a fragment of the whole code @Teemu

Comment: @envyM6 C´mon, have you tried to read the cookie after `document.write`?

Comment: Well the intention was to create a page it counter using cookie and reset it to zero using that button. @PointedEars

Comment: If you guys are interested I can create a new post with the whole code and we can work together to improve it... Should I?

Comment: @Teemu yeah I did... I have to refresh the whole page to get things started again. and yeah `document.write` clears everything and writes zero to the page so basically .... meh

Comment: What did you intend with `document.write(0)`?

Comment: to show the counter is zero... let me create a fiddle for you with whole thing

Comment: Sorry guys Jsfiddle is not allowing me to use `document.write`

Comment: @envyM6 Only you can see in your fiddle is the hard-coded value your wrote to a _new_ document with `document.write`, it's not the value of your cookie. Your cookie is gone, as well as the original page... Don't use `document.write`, the simplest replacement is `document.body.innerHTML+=...;`

Comment: @Teemu its not me only... I have also made some changes... like `document.getElementById("out").innerHTML = x;`

Comment: Using `gEBI()` is even better. Your fiddle has a conflict with `noWrap - <in head>` and `onLoad`. If you open your console, you can see an error message ("cdelete is not defined") after clicking on the button, but the cookie survives :)

Comment: @Teemu thanks for the feedback.. but the counter only works on chrome at the moment. on firefox and opera the counter just resets upon window close. but on chrome it stays and picks up where it left off

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51067/discussion-between-envym6-and-teemu)

Answer (score 0):

You could try an `inline` confirm box:

```
<input type="button" value="Expire Cookie" onclick="if(confirm('Reset hit counter ?')) { document.cookie = 'visits=0';document.write(0); }" />
```

Although this is a way to do it, I would suggest that you add a proper event handler to the input button.

Comment: Do you know how [`document.write`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.write) actually works?

Comment: Yes I do. But the question was to present a confirmation box.

Comment: I can just imagine OP's face, when (s)he tries your code and the page goes blank... What would happen to `document.cookie` then?